# memory error followed by dead kernel on AWS using c4.4xlarge instance (5GB data)

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, jupyter

I am running analysis of 5GB data on jupyter notebook from AWS instance. I am using Deep learning Ubuntu Version 20 AMI and the instance is c4.4xlarge, which has 30 GB RAM. I am only doing some basic stuff on the dataframe, like dropping, merging yet. I have not conducted any machine learning or deep learning. But, it already shows low memory. Then, the kernel is dead. 
Why is there a memory problem given that the AMI has 30 GB RAM. Also, is there a way to check the memory usage in AWS?

Comment: Since it is the Kernel, I think you are over loading the CPU Cache (on-board memory).  RAM may not be getting used at all.

Comment: Thank you, Wookies! Is switching to an instance with larger CPU the only option I should take?